# Is semicolon really needed after declarations in x++?

Tags: declaration, axapta, x++

As said in the book **Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 Programming: Getting Started** it´s needed to put semicolons after declarations in x++:

> The extra semicolon after the variable
>   declaration is mandatory as long as
>   the first line of code is not a
>   keyword. The semicolon tells the
>   compiler that variable declarations
>   have come to an end. You cannot
>   declare new variables after this
>   semicolon.

(copied directly from the book, unchanged, if needed I'll remove it)

However, when I remove the semicolon and run the job, there's absolutely no error or problem:

```
static void Job1(Args _args)
{
    str string1 = "STACKOVERFLOW";
    ;
    print string1;
    pause;
}
```

works just as

```
static void Job2(Args _args)
{
     str string1 = "STACKOVERFLOW";

     print string1;
     pause;
}
```

Is it really needed? Should I get used to using it?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question when I came across http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc967415.aspx. Good question!

Comment: for more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mfp/archive/2008/04/24/what-s-up-with-this-semicolon.aspx

Comment: Your answer is right there in the definition. "mandatory as long as the first line of code is not a keyword." `print` is a keyword.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's explained rather elegantly [here](http://sysdictcoder.com/blog/the-lone-semicolon/).

A key quote [emphasis mine]:

> *"The reason you need that extra semicolon is because **the compiler can’t always see where the variable declarations end**. If you don’t help a little, it will make a guess. And it’s not very good at guessing."*
>
> While the compiler is analyzing the code it **checks if the first word on a line matches the name of a type (AOT object). If it’s a type name the compiler treats the line as a variable declaration.** In this case a variable name should be next.

Answer (score 9):

With the release of AX 2012 there is no need to put the additional semicolon after variable declaration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa636895.aspx

Comment: Strictly speaking, this isn't true: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc641200.aspx 
"Starting in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 you rarely need to include a semicolon before the first statement in your X++ methods. However, you need the semi-colon in X++ methods that call static methods in the .NET Framework."
More on it here: http://erptechnician.net/2012/06/30/method-not-found-error-xpp-call-static-method-dotnet-class/
That is there are cases, however seldom they might be, when the semicolon is required even in AX 2012.

Answer (score 6):

You only need the semicolon if the body of your code doesn't start with a keyword. In your example, your code starts with `print`, which is a built in keyword. If you had tried to start you code with: `string1+=".COM";` you would receive an error.

Dynamics AX 2009 is the last version of AX that will require the extra semicolon.  AX 6.0 should fix this: [mfp's two cents: What's up with this semicolon?](http://blogs.msdn.com/mfp/archive/2008/04/24/what-s-up-with-this-semicolon.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You really don't need the lovely semicolon (you don't get a compilation error) when the ***next word*** after declarations (if any) is not some keyword recognized by compilator like a type (an EDT, table, class, ...)

For example:

```
void method1()
{
    CustTable    custTable;

    custTable = CustTable::find("cust");
}
```

**ERROR!** as compiler can't separate the class declaration block of the start of the X++ code. When compilator reads the second line it doesn't know if custTable is a new variable or is part of the X++ code. So that, you need the extra semicolon to say the compiler where is the end of declarations (really, where is the start of X++ code).

```
void method1()
{
    CustTable    custTable;

    if (custTable)
    {
        // stuff happens
    }        
}
```

**WORKS!** as compiler knows that you can't declare a variable of type `if` (it's a reserved keyword, obviously) so it's clear that this is the beginning of X++ code and you can't declare variables after this line.

This works that way even if there is no variable declarations:

```
CustTable method1()
{
    custTable = CustTable::find("cust"); // custTable may exists in the context
    return custTable;
}
```

**ERROR!** `custTable` may be a decaration, or X++ code like that example.

```
CustTable method1()
{
    return CustTable::find("cust");
}
```

**WORKS!** as `return` can't be a declaration.

**EXTRA:**

```
void method1()
{
    info("This should work, ya?");
}
```

This should work (as `info` is not a type), isn't it? ... but it doesn't! Why? Because `info` is an special kernel method that will be replaced to its full name: `Global::info()`, first token will be `Global` after the precompiler replacement, and `Global` is a class.